# Restrict user access in Linux

Tags: linux, rhel5, selinux, gnome

I am given a task to configure a RedHat Enterprise Linux 5 Gnome PC such that a specific user - say USER1 will have very limited desktop access. The requirements include:

1. Access to all of the desktop menus (Application, Places, System) and icons (Computer, User's Home etc.) must be restricted.
2. Restrict shell access to most of the folders but user's own home folder.
3. This user (USER1) should only have few pre-configured icons/shortcuts on their desktop and that's all he/she should be able to run/double-click.
4. This user (USER1) should not be able to run any shell commands that will affect any  file/folder but their own.

Basically it's all locked-down PC with very limited functionality available to this particular user. If another authorized user or root logs in - then all usual bells and whistles should be available as normal.

We have achieved this on Windows using **Local Security Settings** but I am not sure how to do that in Linux.

I have heard of **SELinux** and have tried using 'SELinux Management Tool' but either it's not very useful or I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: Why does it need to be so restrictive? By design, a normal (unprivileged) user shouldn't be able to cause problems for others.

Comment: Also, (4) is satisfied by a default installation.

Comment: @Ian McLaird: Thanks for the comment. I wasn't sure about Serverfault as I saw few questions about SELinux here.

Comment: @Mechanical snail: It's the customer Requirement. This user should be able to perform very few actions that normal privileged user can and be restricted from all the other. Being a non-admin I can't think of how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what kce mentioned here is what I found:

[RedHat Deployment Guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/4/pdf/rhd-dg-en.pdf) on Page 10 onwards explains almost exactly what I want to do. 
[This](http://sayamindu.randomink.org/soc/deployment_guide/deployment_guide.html) page also explains a little bit.

Answer (score 6):

> - Restrict shell access to most of the folders but user's own home
>     folder.
> - This user (USER1) should not be able to run any shell commands that
>     will affect any file/folder but their own.

The standard Linux permissions scheme should account for this. Unprivileged users can't modify anything that doesn't belong to them, nor access to folders where important system information is stored.

> - Access to all of the desktop menus (Application, Places, System)
>     and icons (Computer, User's Home etc.) must be restricted.

1. Modify the panel and desktop so that none of the offending icons or
   applets are available.
2. Use [gconftool2](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gconftool-2) to set the following keys (under
   apps/panel/global):

   - Checking `disable_force_quit` will prevent the users ability to forcibly close a panel applet.
   - Checking `disable_lock_screen` will prevent the user from displaying the screen saver and password protecting the screen.
   - Checking `disable_log_out` will prevent the user from logging out of, shutting down, or restarting the computer.
   - Checking `locked_down` will prevent the user from making any changes to the panels.
3. Set the following keys under desktop/gnome/lockdown:

   - Checking `disable_command_line` This also disable the "Run Program" dialog.
   - Checking `disable_lock_screen` will prevent the user from locking the screen.
   - Checking `disable_printing` will prevent the user from printing things to an attached printer.
   - Checking `disable_print_setup` will prevent access to all "Print Setup" dialogs.
   - Checking `disable_save_to_disk` will prevent the user from saving anything to the hard drive.
   - Checking `disable_user_switching` will prevent the user from switching to another account while the current session is active.
4. You will want to make these settings mandatory (otherwise a knowledgeable user can just un-set them). See the [Gnome Deployment Guide](http://library.gnome.org/admin/deployment-guide/) for more information.

It sounds like what you're *really* looking for is a way to make Gnome behave like a kiosk. There's a few guides for that:

- http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/linuxkiosk/ubuntu01.htm
- http://library.gnome.org/admin/deployment-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I think chrooting might be a start, you restrict the user to his own home folder and jail him there, he can't just go somewhere else, so he can only edit his own files. There is a very nice guide here : 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-rssh-chroot-jail-setup.html